# Store the security verification code in Redis

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi project. Due to project requirements, I need a graphic verification code when registering a user. Are there any recommendations that are useful? In addition, how to combine Redis to store it in Redis.Like this, but what I need is numbers and 4 digits.Thank you for your time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMLdw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a Demo based on your needs, you can refer to it.

First, I used the `Bitmap` library to generate the graphic verification code, the code is as follows:

```
public class VerifyCodeHelper
    {
        public static Bitmap CreateVerifyCode(out string code)
        {
            //Create a Bitmap object and draw
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(200, 60);
            Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            graph.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, 200, 60);
            Font font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 48, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            Random r = new Random();
            string letters = "0123456789";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //Add random 4 numbers
            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            {
                string letter = letters.Substring(r.Next(0, letters.Length - 1), 1);
                sb.Append(letter);
                graph.DrawString(letter, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), x * 38, r.Next(0, 15));
            }
            code = sb.ToString();

            //Confuse the background
            Pen linePen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 2);
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
                graph.DrawLine(linePen, new Point(r.Next(0, 199), r.Next(0, 59)), new Point(r.Next(0, 199), r.Next(0, 59)));
            return bitmap;
        }

    }
```

Then create the controller to call the API to generate the graphic verification code. Then configure Redis：

```
Package Manager:
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis
```

To integrate Redis functionality configure the 'AddStackExchangeRedisCache()' service in startup file.

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => {
 options.Configuration = "localhost:6379";
});
```

Then inject the IDistributedCache interface into our endpoint controller.

Then use the 4-digit random number received by _distributedCache.SetString to store it in the database, all the codes are as follows:

```
[ApiController]
    public class VerifyCodeController : Controller
    {

        private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

        public VerifyCodeController(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
        {
            _distributedCache = distributedCache;
        }

        [Route("get_captcha")]
        public Object VerifyCode()
        {
            string code = "";
            Bitmap bitmap = VerifyCodeHelper.CreateVerifyCode(out code);
           _distributedCache.SetString("code",code);

            base.HttpContext.Session.SetString("CheckCode",code);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Gif);
            return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/gif");
        }

    }
```

The overall Startup.cs configuration is as follows. If you make an error when calling the API, remember to check these configurations carefully:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => {
                options.Configuration = "localhost:6379";
            });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            });
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Final result：

Generated graphic verification code：

[image]

Redis data:

[image]

Comment: Great! But I need to encrypt and store the key of the verification code, I went back to do it, thank you!